# Creating a List of QPushButtons

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qlistwidget, qpushbutton

I'd like to create a list of QPushButtons that are added and removed at runtime. I figure that an item view widget would accomplish this (QListWidget). The reason for wanting to use an item view instead of a layout is that I would like to scroll through a list of buttons instead of just trying make them all fit. However, I don't see too many examples of QListWidgets being used to store a QPushButtons.

I'd like some tips, pointers, or examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not use `QListWidget` in this case. Create a widget with a layout and all your buttons. Then put in `QScrollArea`.

Comment: This seems a bit complicated, but it also seems to be the right approach. I'm in the process of testing this.

Comment: Depending on the situation I still would prefere the ListWidget and just create own ItemDelegates which handle my buttons. The QScrollArea gives you more flexibility while the QListWidget really does just lets you create a "list of child widgets"

Comment: @sj755 it should not be more complicated to just use standard QGridLayout or QVBoxLayout to make a stack of buttons! It seems like overkill to use QListWidget to do such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can add widgets to `QListWidget` using its [setIndexWidget](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) function.

Comment: or `setItemWidget()`, which is specific to `QListWidget`